# laravel 5.5- error Trying to get property of non-object (views\pledges\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I have been getting this property of non object error
The campaign, pledge and member models are connected to each other i.e they have relationships amongest themselves
Here is my campaign model

```
   class Campaign extends Model
{
    protected $table = "campaigns";

    public function pledges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pledge::class, 'campaign_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Here is my pledge model

```
   class Pledge extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pledges";

    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Campaign::class, 'id', 'campaign_id');
    }


    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'id', 'member_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my Member model

```
   class Member extends Model
{
    protected $table = "members";

    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class, 'borrower_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function pledges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pledge::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function contributions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contribution::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MemberTag::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventAttendance::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
    public function families()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FamilyMember::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Family::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Here is my view.pledge.blade file i dont know why am getting the trying to get non-object error, your input would be greatly appreciated guys.

```
<div class="widget-content nopadding">
            <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Campaign</th>
                  <th>Member</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  
           
                <tr class="gradeX">
             

                    @foreach ($pledge as $pledges)
                      <td>{{ $pledges->member->first_name }}</td>
                       <td>{{ $pledges->campaign->campaign_id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->pledges->amount }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->pledges->date }}</td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Here is the pledge controller for easy debugging. Really appreciate the feedback so far.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Campaign;
use App\Member;
use App\Pledge;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Pledgecontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {   

        $member= Member::all();
        $campaign= Campaign::all();
        $pledge= Pledge::all();
        return view ('pledges.index', compact ('member', 'campaign', 'pledge'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $member= Member::all();
        $campaign= Campaign::all();
        $pledge= Pledge::all();
        return view ('pledges.create', compact ('member', 'campaign', 'pledge'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $pledge= new Pledge;
        $pledge->member_id = $request->member_id;
        $pledge->campaign_id = $request->campaign_id;
        $pledge->amount = $request->amount;
        $pledge->date = $request->date;
        $pledge->notes = $request->notes;
        $pledge->save();

        return redirect (route('pledge.index'));
        // return $request->all();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `$pledge` coming from? Can you show your controller code?

Comment: i have already uploaded the pledge controller code above, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct relationships:

```
class Pledge extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pledges";

    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class, 'campaign_id');
    }


    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'member_id');
    }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't do this since you don't have pledges that have pledges:

```
$pledges->pledges->amount
```

Also, if not all pledges belong to a member, you need to check this:

```
optional($pledges->member)->first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `$pledge` is empty or not.

```
     @if(!empty($pledge))  
       @foreach ($pledge as $pledges)
           <td>{{ $pledges->member->first_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ $pledges->campaign->campaign_id }}</td>
           <td>{{ $pledges->pledges->amount }}</td>
           <td>{{ $pledges->pledges->date }}</td>
       @endforeach
     @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to be careful:

1. `belongsTo` relation can return null.
2. I'm not sure if you are 'eager loading' your data. I highly recommend you to do that, otherwise you'll have a [N + 1 problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).
3. Pledges.. -> pledges? are you sure? I can't see this n your Pledge model.
4. `foreach($yourArray as $arrayItem)` not the opposite.
5. If you want to check if a collection is empty, use `$pledges->isEmpty()`

Change your controller "pledge" query to:

`$pledge= Pledge::with(['campaign','member'])->get();`

> ```
> <table>
>   @if ($pledges->isEmpty())
>     <tr>
>       <td colspan="4">Empty!</td>
>     </tr>
>   @else
>     @foreach ($pledges as $pledge)
>       <tr>
>         <td>{{ $pledge->member ? $pledge->member->first_name : '' }}</td>
>         <td>{{ $pledge->campaign ? $pledge->campaign->campaign_id : '' }}</td>
>         <!-- Are you sure about these two lines? -->
>         <td>{{ $pledge->pledges->amount }}</td>
>         <td>{{ $pledge->pledges->date }}</td>
>       </tr>
>     @endforeach
>   @endif
> </table>
> ```

Comment: yeah thanks a bunch it should be: already corrected it
<!-- Are you sure about these two lines? -->
        <td>{{ $pledges->amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ $pledges->date }}</td>
please check above i have added the pledge controller code check above.

Comment: The pledge controller is uploaded above in my question